# Python - Moving an object\label\button and changing it's attribute

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm learning python and the book that is teaching me gives me two ways to create a label using tkinker:

```
self.canvas.create_text(30,10,text="Welcome",tags="text")
```

&

```
self.lbl = Label(frame1, text = "Welcome")
```

In the former example, moving it is easy:

```
self.canvas.move("text", 1, 0)
```

In the latter example, changing it's background color is easy:

```
self.lbl["bg"] = "red"
```

However I do *not* know how to both move it AND change it's background color in either example, at least not how to move it incrementally. I can do this:

```
 self.lbl.place(x=2)
```

But unless I can get the x coordinate ahead of time, I can only move it once. I could set it ahead of time, but I'd like to avoid that option if possible.

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish? Are you trying to animate text moving across a canvas, or are you building a traditional GUI with buttons and labels? You'll get two completely different answers for those two scenarios.

Comment: Well, it's for a class I'm taking. I already turned in the assignment using the "set x coordinate first" method, so I'm not cheating, I'd just like a better way to do it. What it is, is a label that you can move to the right and the left when you press on of the corresponding buttons, and a bunch of radio buttons where you can set the background color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to do both.

Firstly, `Canvas` text does not have a background, but you can create your own with a rectangle.

```
text = self.canvas.create_text(30, 10, text="Welcome", tags="text")
# The canvas.bbox method returns the corner coordinates of the provided item id.
rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.canvas.bbox(text), fill='red')
# Then you need to reposition the rectangle so that it is behind the text.
self.canvas.lower(rect, text)
```

From there you just move them the same way as you mentioned in your question.  Adding a  group tag to both the text and rectangle would save you from having to move both items separately.

Secondly, you can get the current x, y coordinates of a widget with the `.winfo_x()` and `.winfo_y()` methods.  So moving the `Label` becomes a simple matter of addition/subtraction:

```
self.lbl.place(x=self.lbl.winfo_x()+2)
```

I do not know of a method that moves a widget in increments as the move method does for the canvas.

As for which is best, I can't think of much between them.  I suppose using a `Canvas` would mean you couldn't overlap any other widgets that may be in the window, since the text would just scroll out of view, and if you start using the `ttk` version of `Label` then styling isn't quite as straight forward, although it's not difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much, that winfo_x and winfo_y seem to be exactly what I was looking for. Does that not move it in increments though?

Comment: @MarcelMarino All I meant was that those methods give you the current x, y coordinates and you have to add your increment to them, whereas Canvas.move just takes the increment on it's own.